# Overriding of operator<< in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I'm working on a project for my school in C++

I have 2 class : Employe and Teacher.
Teacher derived from Employe and has overrides of his functions.

We override the operator `<<` to print some information of the Employes or Teachers.
Each class has a `const int attribute LevelAcces_`.
For **Employe**, it's **5** and for **Teacher** it's **20**.

when I create an Teacher in my main.cpp, I call the override of operator<< of Teacher to print his information.
So this function is called :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Teacher& pTeacher){
    os << (pTeacher);
    return os;
}
```

But, the **function calls itself** with the line `"os << (pTeacher);"` and **does a loop that causes a stack overflow**.

**I want that the line `"os << (pTeacher)"` calls the operator<< of my class Employe and not of my class Teacher.**

Override of operator<< in Employe :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Employe& pEmploye){
    os << "Name: " << pEmploye.name_ << endl;
    os << "Class: " << pEmploye.getClass() << endl;
    os << "LevelAcces: " << pEmploye.getLevelAccess() << endl;
    return os;
}
```

I tried to cast my Teacher into Employe but when it prints the message, LevelAcces is 5 (and I want 20, because my Employe is a Teacher).

I also tried to use Employe::operator<< but operator<< is not a member of Employe so it doesn't work...

So, here is my question :

**How can I do to use my operator<< of Employe in my operator<< of Teacher and print the right information (LevelAccess = 20 and not 5) ?**

*I was also thinking of "virtual" but our professor tells us that there is not need to use this word.*

Thanks in advance :)

Here is a more complete code :

main.cpp:

```
Teacher Garry("Garry");
cout << Garry << endl;
```

Employe.cpp :

```
#include "Employe.h"

using namespace std;

Employe::Employe(){
    name_ = "";
}

Employe::Employe(string pName){
    name_ = pName;
}

string Employe::getName() const{
    return name_;
}

unsigned int Employe::getLevelAccess() const{
    return levelAccess_;
}

string Employe::getClass() const{
    return typeid(*this).name();
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Employe& pEmploye){
    os << "Name: " << pEmploye.name_ << endl;
    os << "Class: " << pEmploye.getClass() << endl;
    os << "LevelAcces: " << pEmploye.getLevelAccess() << endl;
    return os;
}
```

With this in Employe.h :

```
private:
    static const unsigned int LevelAccess_ = 5;
```

Teacher.cpp :

```
#include "teacher.h"
using namespace std;

Teacher::Teacher(string pName){
    nom_ = pName;
}

unsigned int Teacher::getLevelAccess() const{
    return(Employe::getLevelAccess() + accessTeacher_); 
}
string Teacher::getClass() const{
    return typeid(*this).name();
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Teacher& pTeacher){
        os << (pTeacher);
        return os;
}
```

With this is Teacher.h :

```
static const unsigned int accesTeacher_ = 15;
```

Comment: Please, show in your question, the definitions of Teacher and Employee.

Comment: Any relevant code to this that you could post? A COMPLETE example would be REALLY nice, but at least the code that sets `accessEmploye_` to  different values would be a start...

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is the following: define only one

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Employe& pEmploye)
{
    return pEmploye.display(os);
}
```

for the base of the hierarchy,
in which you call a protected member function `virtual display()` that is overridden by each derived class and to which the display is being delegated. This is sometime call the NVI (non-virtual interface) idiom. It works like this:

```
class Employee
{
    // ...
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Employee& pEmployee)
    {
        return pEmployee.display(os);
    }
protected:
    virtual ostream& display(ostream& os) const
    {
        // implement it here
        return os;
    }
};

class Teacher: public Employee
{
    // ....
protected:
    ostream& display(ostream& os) const override
    {
        // implement it here
        return os;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's a good idea but my teacher says :

"In Teacher, use a friend function operator << to print all the attributes of Teacher (Think to use the operator<< of Employe)".

And I can't create an other function (I have a paper that says all the function that I have to create).

Comment: @Aymeric, ok, then use Matt's suggestion with the casting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cast:

```
os << static_cast<const Employe &>(pTeacher);
```

The `&` is important.

To make the call to the member function call `Teacher::getLevelAccess()` from an `Employe` reference, you have to make that function virtual. (Do this in `teacher.h`).  `getClass()` should be `virtual` also.

---

NB. You keep saying things like "Override of `operator<<` in Employe :" , however you do not have overloaded `operator<<` in Employe . You have a free function which takes `Employe` as argument.

Comment: Hate when that happens =(