# How can I use the insertion operator with polymophism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, ostream

I want to implement a composite pattern where I can print the contents using std::cout

When I print, the base class insertion operator (operator<<) is used instead of the most derived type. How can I cause the most derived type operator to be used?

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    int i;
public:
    Base(int _i) : i(_i) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    friend inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Base& value) { return os << "i: " <<  value.i; }
    friend inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, shared_ptr<Base> value) { return os << "i: " <<  value->i; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int x;
public:
    Derived(int _x) : Base(2*_x), x(_x) {}

    friend inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Derived& value) { return os << "x: " << value.x; }
    friend inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, shared_ptr<Derived> value) { return os << "x: " << value->x; }
};

int main () {
    Base* a = new Base(1);
    Derived* d = new Derived(6);
    Base* b = new Derived(7);

    shared_ptr<Base> ba = make_shared<Base>(3);
    shared_ptr<Derived> de = make_shared<Derived>(4);
    shared_ptr<Base> bd = make_shared<Derived>(5);

    cout << "a is: " << a << endl;
    cout << "*a is: " << *a << endl;
    cout << "d is: " << d << endl;
    cout << "*d is: " << *d << endl;
    cout << "b is: " << b << endl;
    cout << "*b is: " << *b << endl << endl;

    cout << "ba is: " << ba << endl;
    cout << "*ba is: " << *ba << endl;
    cout << "de is: " << de << endl;
    cout << "*de is: " << *de << endl;
    cout << "bd is: " << bd << endl;
    cout << "*bd is: " << *bd << endl;

    delete a;
    delete d;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

[live code](http://cpp.sh/6lxw)

This spits out

```cpp
a is: 0x1fe2bb0
*a is: i: 1
d is: 0x1fe2bd0
*d is: x: 6
b is: 0x1fe2bf0
*b is: i: 14

ba is: i: 3
*ba is: i: 3
de is: x: 4
*de is: x: 4
bd is: i: 10
*bd is: i: 10
```

But I would like to see *b print 7 and bd print 5 (ie. use the Derived class' insertion operator)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after searching a lot more, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466862/1669250) answer. After smacking my head and saying 'of course',  I summarize:

Don't overload the insertion operator since you can't make it virtual (it's not a member function), instead declare a virtual function in the base class that is overridden in the child classes. The insertion operator uses this function:

```cpp
class Base {
    ...
    friend inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, shared_ptr<Base> value) { return value->display(os, value); }
    virtual ostream& display(ostream& os) { os << "i: " << i << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    ...
    ostream& display(ostream& os) { os << "x: " << x << endl; }
};
```

[live code](http://cpp.sh/7v6z)

Comment: A more usual name than `display()` is `put()`.